# Hello World in Visual Studio 2015 TSX file ( React.js and TypeScript )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am new to React.js and TypeScript and am trying to get a simple Hello World sample working. I added react-d.ts, react-dom.d.ts to my Typings folder.  When I run the site in debug mode I get "require is not defined" on line 1 of the typescript file.  How do I define this?

--------- index.html file: --------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>TypeScript Test</title>

   <!-- References. -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Before React Output</h1>
   <div id="content"></div>

   <script src="Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

----------- Test.tsx file: -----------------

```
import React = require('react');
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

interface MyProps {
   name: string;
}

class HelloWorld extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
   constructor(props: MyProps) {
      super(props);
   }
   render() {
      return (<div> Hello {this.props.name} </div>);
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld name="World" />,  document.getElementById('content'));
```

Here are my TypeScript settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this code to work by adding the react-globals.d.ts typescript definitions file to my VS project, but I also had to remove the two lines that did the "import React = 'react';".  I guess the CommonJS import syntax is not required for external modules when I am not bundling everything into 1 javascript file.

I could also get the project to work if I created a bundle.js of all the javascript files using Gulp and Browserify.  Maybe this is the better way since I don't have to use the script tags for React and it still works.

The problem with this method is that I don't know how to set break points in the individual typescript files.  I can only set break points for debugging in the giant bundled javascript file.  I finally gave up and logged a call with Microsoft to try and figure out how to make all this new technology work together. Good grief Charlie Brown!

Microsoft got back to me and said that [TypeScript version 1.8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta.aspx) (in beta) will solve all of these bundling problems.  I guess that means that Gulp and Browserify won't be needed in Visual Studio for bundling anymore.